# Is there a way to change the page number in the TOC when inserting a PDF?

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, pdfpages

At the beginning of my document, i insert a 3 page pdf. In the TOC, i reference the items in the aforementioned 3 page pdf. However, the page number beside the TOC is incorrect. Is there a way to change this page number. Here is a MWE

I import to LaTeX like this:

```
\includepdf[pages=-]{resources/frontmatter.pdf}
```

Right now I am putting this after \begin{document}

```
% add signature block stuff
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Signature Block}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Record of Revision}
\setcounter{page}{4}
```

then this is what my TOC shows:

[image: TOC]

I want the page number beside signature block and record of revision to be 2 and 3 respectively. I don't care about whether the TOC hyperlinks to the Signature block or Record of revisions; just want to change the page number.

Comment: If you have the source code, use that, not the PDF.  My second choice would be to retype the whole thing.  \inlucdepdf is a distant third.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`pdfpages`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) provides `addtotoc` as an option for specifying what of the included document should be added to the ToC. It takes 5 arguments:

```
addtotoc={<page number>, <section>, <level>, <heading>, <label>}
```

So you can include the individual components of the document and place the appropriate `addtotoc` arguments to ensure proper formatting and linking.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages,lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{secnumdepthstore}% For storing whatever secnumdepth is

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\setcounter{secnumdepthstore}{\value{secnumdepth}}% Store value of secnumdepth counter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}% Avoid numbering sections
\includepdf[
  pages=1-2,
  addtotoc={%
    1,% <page number>
    section,% <section>
    1,% <level>
    Signature block,% <heading>
    signature_block% <label>
  }
]{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}

\includepdf[
  pages=3,
  addtotoc={%
    3,% <page number>
    section,% <section>
    1, % <level>
    Record of revision,% <heading>
    record_of_revision% <label>
  }
]{example-image-letter-numbered.pdf}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{secnumdepthstore}}% Restore section numbering up to secnumdepth

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Since the document class you're using wasn't specified, I'm capturing the value of `secnumdepth` (that specifies what sectional units are numbered or not) prior to the inclusion of pages - setting it to `0` so `\section`s (which are at level `1`) aren't numbered - and reset it after including the pages.

Comment: Should have mentioned, I am using documentclass article

Comment: Worked! thanks, I appreciate it.

Comment: @AustinBenny: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)

Comment: Just did. Also I was wondering why that first \newcounter{secnumdepthstore} is before creating the document. I tested my documented by moving it after \begin{document} and my document was the same.

Comment: @AustinBenny: It's typical to have a separation between document content (the text) and structure (the setup). The structure includes definitions (like I did with `\newcounter`). However, there's no requirement to have the definitions before `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that this corresponds to the TOC entry for a `\section*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifodd\value{page}%
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin}%
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip}% first baseline
  \ifnum\value{page}=2\relax \put (\dimen0,-\dimen1)
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Signature Block}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{page}=3\relax \put (\dimen0,-\dimen1)
    {\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Record of Revision}}\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

---

Just for fun, here is a hypertext compatible version for `\section`.  You can even adjust the location using `\put`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\ifodd\value{page}%
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin}%
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen0}{\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin}%
  \fi
  \setlength{\dimen1}{\dimexpr 1in+\topmargin+\headheight+\headsep+\topskip}% first baseline
  \ifnum\value{page}=2\relax \put (\dimen0,-\dimen1)
    {\refstepcounter{section}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}Signature Block}}\fi
  \ifnum\value{page}=3\relax \put (\dimen0,-\dimen1)
    {\refstepcounter{section}{\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\string\numberline{\thesection}Record of Revision}}}\fi}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! this is a great solution. the hyperlinks would come in handy